# Reference request regarding certain problem in Group and representation theory.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Suppose $G$  is a finite group. Now, we consider the following

$G^{2}=\{ g^{2}|g\in G \}\ $. I want to know how this set might look like for different $G$. I have heard that this problem is tackled through representation theory and I am looking for references where I can find discussions about this problem.

Thanks in advance!!